# When running WebDriver with Chrome browser, getting message, "Only local connections are allowed" even though browser launches properly

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run Chrome browser using WebDriver, I am getting following message on console. Please let me know how to resolve it.

> "Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267521) on port 22582 " "Only local
>   connections are allowed."

Here is my sample code:

```java
public class Browserlaunch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32   \\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() ;
        driver.get("http://webdunia.com");
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 106):

This is an informational message only. What the message is telling you is that the chromedriver executable will only accept connections from the local machine.

Most driver implementations (the Chrome driver and the IE driver for sure) create a HTTP server. The language bindings (Java, Python, Ruby, .NET, etc.) all use a JSON-over-HTTP protocol to communicate with the driver and automate the browser. Since the HTTP server is simply listening on an open port for HTTP requests generated by the language bindings, connections to the HTTP server started by the language bindings are only allowed to come from other processes on the same host. Note carefully that this limitation does not apply to connections the  *browser* can make to outside websites; rather it simply prevents *incoming* connections from other websites.

Comment: In my case the test stop after open up the browser and page is empty. In the url `Not secure   data:, ` So in that sense this is an issue. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: so if I access a website that uses https communication with selenium using driver.get(https://etc...) does that mean the information sent to that site are encrypted with https?

Comment: The HTTP (not secured) communication referred to in this answer is between the language bindings (you Selenium code in Java, C#, Python, etc.) and the browser driver (chromedriver, geckodriver, etc.). The communication between the browser and the website is unchanged. If you’re using HTTPS in the browser, the communication between the browser and the web server should still be encrypted.

Comment: I have the same issue :/ Was this issue ever fixed?

Answer (score 17):

Not necessarily the best practice, but my environment was a local network with several machines which needed access to the selenium.

When running the chromedriver, you can pass through a param like so :

`chromedriver --whitelisted-ips=""`

This will basically whitelist all IP's, not always an ideal solution of course and be careful with it for production enviornments, but you should be presented with a verbose warning :

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333244
>   (15fb740a49ab3660b8f8d496cfab2e4d37c7e6ca) on port 9515 All remote
>   connections are allowed. Use a whitelist instead!

A work-around at best, but it works.

[Relative check-in](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=267444&view=revision)

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the exact same errors. I battled this issue for a few hours today. It seemed to be caused by a mismatch between the versions of chromedriver and selenium-server-standalone. The config.js file was referencing a directory that had chromedriver 2.9 and selenium-server-standalone 2.35.0. Once I made sure we were referencing 2.10 and 2.42.2, it worked.

Answer (score 8):

After hours of analysis reading tons of logs and sourcecode, finally found problem. And it is quite easy to solve it.

in sinle line: you need to pass --whitelisted-ips= into **chrome driver** (not chrome!) executables

You can do it in few ways:

If you use ChromeDriver locally/directly from code, just insert lines below before ChromeDriver init

```java
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps", "");
```

If you use it remotely (eg. selenium hub/grid) you need to set system property when node starts, like in command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps= testClass etc...
```

or docker by passing `JAVA_OPTS` env

```yaml
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    container_name: chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
```

Answer (score 7):

Chromedriver is a WebDriver. WebDriver is an open-source tool for automated testing of web apps across many browsers. It provides capabilities for navigating to web pages, user input, JavaScript execution, and more. When you run this driver, it will enable your scripts to access this and run commands on Google Chrome.

This can be done via scripts running in the local network (`Only local connections are allowed.`) or via scripts running on outside networks (`All remote connections are allowed.`). It is always safer to use the Local Connection option. By default your Chromedriver is accessible via port `9515`.

To answer the question, it is just an informational message. You don't have to worry about it.

Given below are both options.

```
$ chromedriver

Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

This is by whitelisting all IPs.

```
$ chromedriver --whitelisted-ips=""

Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 9515
All remote connections are allowed. Use a whitelist instead!
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me when I had to fix an old project that had not been looked at in a while. The chromedriver associated to the project was not compatible with my version of chrome, so when I updated the chromedriver it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is an informational message only. It means nothing if your test scripts and chromedriver are on the same machine then it is possible to add the "whitelisted-ips" option .your test will run fine.However if you use chromedriver in a grid setup, this message will not appear

Comment: how do I add this bro -  "whitelisted-ips"  . I m having the same problem

Comment: How to add the whitelist-ips. i am using windows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to run my commands in the **one and same** terminal, not seperately.

```
nohup sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
java -jar vendor/se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin="/usr/bin/google-chrome" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="vendor/bin/chromedriver"
```

Answer (score 1):

Very often this error appears if you use incompatible versions of Selenium and ChromeDriver.

Selenium 3.0.1 for Maven project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

ChromeDriver 2.27: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: You should explain how he can solve his problem. You just identify the problem but how to solve this? Which versions are compatibel for example?

Comment: I use this combination: selenium-java 3.0.1 + ChromeDriver 2.27 (It supports Chrome v54-56)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, solved it by getting the appropriate webdriver from:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

You can know the exact version of your chrome browser by entering the link:

```
chrome://settings/help
```

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue. This error comes when you use selenium standalone server instead of selenium-java and your selenium standalone server version and browser version has an incompatibility.

i was using: `implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.141.59'` in my build.gradle.

To resolve it i had changed my dependency to selenium-java in build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
```

i was running locally. But if you are running through Selenium grid then you need to
use   `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps", "");` before initializing the ChromeDriver.

Answer (score -4):

I solved this error by installing the browser driver:

1. Navigate your browser to seleniumhq.org website
2. Select the Downloads tab
3. Scroll down the page to the Browser section and download the driver you want by clicking the link, for example, Google Chrome Driver
4. Double-click the downloaded file, for example, chromedriver_mac64(1).zip
5. Double-click the extracted file, for example, chromedriver

Reference:  search YouTube.com for the error

Platform:  macOS High Sierra 10.13.3