# How to setup Chromedriver to run correctly on external links?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the chromedriver setup for my tests like this:

```
mport org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class chromebrowser {
    public static void main()
    {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d://chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("https://google.com/");  
    }
}
```

Upon running the tests I receive the following error in the console:
Starting ChromeDriver 2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7) on port 43827
Only local connections are allowed.

Please note that the chrome window will be opened, with "data:," as text.

How can i set up chromedriver to run on external links?

Comment: Please check below link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-run-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connection

Comment: I saw that post, but it did not provide an answer I could understand or a solution. Can u help me and explain the solution?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do about going *to* external links, ignore the message. What's the issue here? It should be going to Google.com fine.

Comment: Well, it isn't going... that is why i asked for a solution regarding this issue.