# How to use ChromeDriver in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using windows on my system. I downloaded and extracted the chromedriver.exe file and I added it to my path.

Here is my code:

```
package com.chrometester.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class chromeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Tgagn_000\\Desktop\\selenium\\chrome");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

But it comes back with an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: C:\Users\Tgagn_000\Desktop\selenium\chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\Tgagn_000\\Desktop\\selenium\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
```

This should fix it. You should point to the driver file, not to its directory.

Comment: I tried It and it worked but when it loaded the page it returned this
Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 5393
Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-run-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connection

Comment: I ran it again and it run right with out any errors. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the `exe`. Possibly

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Tgagn_000\\Desktop\\selenium\\chrome.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

As error says, you have given directory path and not `.exe` path.

C:\Users\Tgagn_000\Desktop\selenium\chrome\ `chromedriver.exe`

Use below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Tgagn_000\\Desktop\\selenium\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about order of the code:

You have to write setProperty code first then initialize the ChromeDriver()

below code sequence will give you an error

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Below code will work

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```