# Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 11384 Only local connections are allowed

Tags: selenium, webdriver

While running my Script with the latest Chrome Driver from Selenium's website I am getting the following error in the console:
Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 11384
Only local connections are allowed.

Can anyone please throw some light as to why am I getting this?

Comment: You'll want to include some information about your configuration

Comment: Refer to this link and see if it helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-run-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connection