# When running webdriver with IE browser, I'm getting message “Only local connections are allowed” although browser launches properly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

My code is below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium_Software\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);      
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://10.32.147.151/RoSServer/WebClient/DoculiveSimulationExt.asp");
WD.wait(4);
flag=IsObjectPresent.byXpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/input[3]", true);
Click.byXpath("//table[@id='AutoNumber1']/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/input[3]");
```

I'm getting this error:

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 2.53.1.0
>
> Listening on port 5069
>
> Only local connections are allowed

Comment: you can refer to similar query in following link
[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-run-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connection)

Comment: Actually i went through link you pasted.Its nothing to do with chromdriver.

Comment: Also I have taken IEdriver which is compatible from selenium site.But still I am getting error.I have tried all solutions given on that link

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
string DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\Selenium_Software\";

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
driver.get("http://10.32.147.151/RoSServer/WebClient/DoculiveSimulationExt.asp");
...
```

Comment: InternetExplorerDriver accept capability and not string

Comment: InternetExplorerDriver(String) - 
Initializes a new instance of the InternetExplorerDriver class using the specified path to the directory containing IEDriverServer.exe.

Comment: try to look selenium api for better understanding selenium functionality : http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

Comment: Yes tried this solution but somehow it is not showing InternetExplorerDriver(String) constructor in code recommendation,and by using it throwing up error.It is showing undefined contructor.

Comment: i see, you using java .. try to initialize InternetExplorerDriverService service object and in that object defined the driver path after that pass it to the driver initialization

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

People [say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25088200/7790436) "This is an informational message only. What the message is telling you is that the ...driver executable will only accept connections from the local machine."