# Server terminated early with status 1 error with Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message "Only local connections are allowed"

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What Selenium version is compatible with ChromeDriver 2.35?

I am getting error

```
Only local connections are allowed
```

when I am running running gulp-protractor with selenium-server-standalone-jar version 2.53.0.

Updating selenium to the latest version 3.8.1 did not work.

After update to version 3.8.1 I was getting error

```
runnerCli - Server terminated early with status 1
```

Comment: what makes you think the version is the issue here ? You'll probably solve you issue by trying to understand what a local connection is, that is assuming that  "Only local connections are allowed" is an error and not just an information.

Comment: I think version is an issue based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846079/only-local-connections-are-allowed-chrome-selenium-webdriver) and similar posts that suggest problem has to do with version mismatch between chrome driver and selenium server. Also, gulp build was working with older versions of Chrome.

Comment: Did you think to look on the chromedriver website? They list all the versions, and the versions of chrome that they support. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: This is a totally legit question.  Latest versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver have introduced new error messages.

Answer (score 6):

As per the question *"What Selenium version is compatible with ChromeDriver 2.35?"* here are the relevant details :

- *Selenium Client version* : Almost all the recent *Selenium Client* versions are compatible with *ChromeDriver v2.35* . As per best practices along with the moving timelines keep updating the *Selenium Client* versions and *ChromeDriver* versions. They are released after a successful *Compatibility Testing* .
- *Selenium Client version 2.53.x* : *ChromeDriver v2.35* is also compatible with *Selenium Client version 2.53.1* .
- Ideally, you need to download the matching **ChromeDriver** version from [**ChromeDriver Google Storage**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) because:

  - ChromeDriver v100: Supports Chrome version 100
  - ChromeDriver v99: Supports Chrome version 99
  - ChromeDriver v98: Supports Chrome version 98
  - ChromeDriver v97: Supports Chrome version 97
  - ChromeDriver v96: Supports Chrome version 96
  - ChromeDriver v95: Supports Chrome version 95
  - ChromeDriver v94: Supports Chrome version 94
  - ChromeDriver v93: Supports Chrome version 93
  - ChromeDriver v92: Supports Chrome version 92
  - ChromeDriver v91: Supports Chrome version 91
  - ChromeDriver v90: Supports Chrome version 90
  - ChromeDriver v89: Supports Chrome version 89
  - ChromeDriver v88: Supports Chrome version 88
  - ChromeDriver v87: Supports Chrome version 87
  - ChromeDriver v86: Supports Chrome version 86
  - ChromeDriver v85: Supports Chrome version 85
  - ChromeDriver v84: Supports Chrome version 84
  - ChromeDriver v83: Supports Chrome version 83
  - ChromeDriver v82: *Was intentionally skipped*
  - ChromeDriver v81: Supports Chrome version 81
  - ChromeDriver v80: Supports Chrome version 80
  - ChromeDriver v79: Supports Chrome version 79
  - ChromeDriver v78: Supports Chrome version 78
  - ChromeDriver v77: Supports Chrome version 77
  - ChromeDriver v76: Supports Chrome version 76
  - ChromeDriver v75: Supports Chrome version 75
  - ChromeDriver v74: Supports Chrome version 74
  - ChromeDriver v73: Supports Chrome version 73
  - ChromeDriver v2.46: Supports Chrome v71-73
  - ChromeDriver v2.45: Supports Chrome v70-72
  - ChromeDriver v2.44: Supports Chrome v69-71 (same as ChromeDriver 2.43, but with additional bug fixes)
  - ChromeDriver v2.43: Supports Chrome v69-71
  - ChromeDriver v2.42: Supports Chrome v68-70
  - ChromeDriver v2.41: Supports Chrome v67-69
  - ChromeDriver v2.40: Supports Chrome v66-68
  - ChromeDriver v2.39: Supports Chrome v66-68
  - ChromeDriver v2.38: Supports Chrome v65-67
  - ChromeDriver v2.37: Supports Chrome v64-66
  - ChromeDriver v2.36: Supports Chrome v63-65
  - ChromeDriver v2.35: Supports Chrome v62-64
  - ChromeDriver v2.34: Supports Chrome v61-63
  - ChromeDriver v2.33: Supports Chrome v60-62
  - ChromeDriver v2.32: Supports Chrome v59-61
  - ChromeDriver v2.31: Supports Chrome v58-60
  - ChromeDriver v2.30: Supports Chrome v58-60
  - ChromeDriver v2.29: Supports Chrome v56-58
  - ChromeDriver v2.28: Supports Chrome v55-57
  - ChromeDriver v2.27: Supports Chrome v54-56

> **Note**: A few months ago, *Chromium Team* made a [preliminary announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/HvlKWqv34es) that ChromeDriver's versioning model will be changing. Now we are moving forward with the plan. Specifically, ChromeDriver 2.46 will be the last release carrying the major version of 2. Future ChromeDriver releases will carry a version number similar to Chrome release. We will start with a release of ChromeDriver 73 next week, before the Beta release of Chrome 73.

Here is how the new release model will work:

- ChromeDriver will be using the same version number scheme as Chrome. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers for more details.
- Each version of ChromeDriver will support Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, upcoming ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.* will support all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.
- Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released. For example, a new version of ChromeDriver will be release next week to match the Beta release of Chrome m73.
- After the initial release of a new major version, we will release patches as needed. These patches may or may not coincide with updates to Chrome.

> *Source* : [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

---

About the log message **"Only local connections are allowed"** taking out a leaf from JimEvans's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect/25088200#25088200):

This `[info]` log message conveys that the *ChromeDriver* binary will only accept connections from the local machine.

As most of the driver implementations (*GeckoDriver* , *IEDriverServer* and *ChromeDriver*) creates an *HTTP Server* and the Selenium Clients (Java, Python, C#, NodeJS) all uses a *JSON-over-HTTP* protocol to communicate with the *WebDriver* and automates the *Browser Client*. As the HTTP server is only listening on an open port for HTTP requests generated by the client language bindings, connections to the HTTP server started by the client language bindings are restricted to only be allowed to come from the same processes on the same host. This limitation does not apply to connections the browser can make to third-party associated websites, rather it simply prevents incoming connections from other websites.