# How to match different browser version and selenium driver version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

1. Google Chrome 65.0.3325.181 > now which driver version should use
2. 58.0.2 (32-bit) > now which driver version should use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link to see which chromedriver version does support specific chrome versions. It seems that there is no new chromedriver version for the latest chrome version 65.0.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads