# selenium webdriver underlying connection was closed

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using chrome driver 2.37 with selenium webdriver 2.45 for automating test cases for a angular website. I getting a random exception.
"A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:60430/session/4c307f49f3d3bd3169032f27dec0d11e/moveto. The status of the exception was ConnectionClosed, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

I dont know about this port, where it is taking from. Its a random exception which occurs when some action is triggered like click, clear, sendkeys. I cant figure out why & when its happening. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Selenium` version is very old, even for the 2.* versions. Try to update it https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: ChromeDriver explicitly doesn't mentions of any dependency on _Selenium_ versions so you are free to use any _Selenium_ version but _ChromeDriver_ have a dependency on the _Chrome_ version being used. Check the discussion [**Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser)

Comment: My chrome version is 55 and it is compatible with v2.37. what selenium webdriver version should i be using? N what could be the possibl issue?