# org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession chrome

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

i am getting error org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession in selenium webriver when i run my file which will first launch the url and do login . i am using chrome v70 , chrome driver v2.43 and selenium server standalone v 3.13.0. Please can you help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message "Only local connections are allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the selenium server standalone v 3.13.0 from the Library tab of eclipse and importing of Selenium-java v3.13.0 and it will works