# Unable to launch Chrome browser through Selenium in Jenkins on Linux platform

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Jenkins is showing message starting the chromedriver but the chromedriver is not triggered and testcase fails.i dont know why it is happening

Note: the xml created for this code runs successfully on terminal.i think issue is with chromedriver

SELENIUM CODE:

```
   public class cmddd {
      @Test
      public void f() throws InterruptedException {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/dev2/Downloads/newchromedriver/chromedriver");
            WebDriver m = new ChromeDriver();
            m.get("https://www.google.com/");
            System.out.println("passed");
    }
    }


JENKINS OUTPUT:

   Building in workspace /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon
    [seffcon] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins170843147783066328.sh
    + ./cd.sh
    [TestNG] Running:
      /home/dev2/eclipse-workspace/seffcon/cd.xml

    Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 20671
    Only local connections are allowed.

    ===============================================
    Suite
    Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: .: can you provide the code snippet of "Execute Shell" step?

Comment: how can i get that steps from jenkins

Comment: In the jenkins build defination

Comment: i have recently starting working on jenkins, can u please tell me the steps or where exactly i will get execute shell steps

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm  check step no. 6

Comment: same way you have shell step in your build definition

Comment: shell command which i have added in shell steps 
./cd.sh
u can also check this screenshot
 https://prnt.sc/mq6jex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your chromedriver version and chromebrowser version. I had noticed this behaviour when there is a version mismatch.

You can refer this link http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: right now i am using latest chrome driver it is working fine for simple selenium script but  case where i have to take the screenshot of webpage or to check the visibility of any element the test case fails

Comment: i have to run the selenium test case which takes screenshot and check the visibility on Jenkins but the Jenkins is not actually launching then how can the script will take the screenshot and check the visibility

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 20671
Only local connections are allowed.
.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.40*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- Possibly you are using the latest Chrome Browser i.e. *chrome=72.0*
- As per [*ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads):

  - If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20
  - If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69
  - If you are using Chrome version 71, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137
  - For older version of Chrome, please see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748) for the version of ChromeDriver that supports it.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Chrome* version to ***Chrome v72*** level.
- As per [*ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [ChromeDriver v2.46](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/) or [ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=72.0.3626.69/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.