# What does the alphanumeric string displayed in console represents when initiating ChromeDriver through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, console, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What is this alphanumeric number **"9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf"** displayed in the console message after starting chrome driver.

Below is the message:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 9515
>   Only local connections are allowed.

Is it SHA-1 checksum, which is displayed after git commit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alphanumeric number `9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf` in the ChromeDriver starup logs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf) on port 9515
```

refers to the **commit** which is used to build the current version of ChromeDriver.

However, `ChromeDriver 2.24.417431` is a pretty old build and you may like to upgrade to the latest [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.

Now, using `ChromeDriver v78.0.3904.70` the startup log is as follows:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 35520
```

where [`edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5) is exactly the `commit` through which version number was incremented to **78.0.3904.70**

Snapshot:

[image: chromedriver_commit]

Comment: Only local connections are allowed. why this message is displayed,

Comment: For the log message _...Only local connections are allowed..._ see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748)

Answer (score 0):

This is the github version id for the chromedriver in use.

Comment: can you please help me to understand what is git hub version id?

Comment: @GoodVibes chromedriver sorce code is in github, every commit has an id.