# WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error when trying to run webbot using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webbot

I'm trying to automate a process using selenium. When I run the code it gives me the error bellow.

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.22000 x86_64)
```

I have downloaded the new driver and passed the variable in system variables under path. Can anyone please help me figure this out. I'm a student just starting my tech career.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked many times before in similar disguises and the answers have usually advised to match versions. However, i have often struggled to match versions (for various reasons) and this is rather cumbersome when the versions keep changing.

For this reason, I use the `ChromeDriverManager()` which installs the correct version at each time.

You need to install webdriver-manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

And this is the working code

```py
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

You can find the docs here:
https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

This module recognises and has solved a problem for us all:

> It’s boring!!! Moreover every time the new version of driver released, you should go and repeat all steps again and again.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If your first line is true, you should vote to close as a duplicate and not answer the question. [answer]

Comment: @Rob,  noted. I edited the comment because i always find myself comming back to this and having to search.  (I will certainly close duplicates going forwards, so thanks for pointing this out).

Comment: Again, if it's a duplicate, it should be closed. So why not close it now?

Comment: because the answers have always pointed to `matching the versions` (which i have used, but struggled with) and i prefer this method. So i would actually like it to be documented (as i will probably refer back to it myself)...

Comment: I appreciate your answer and found it useful. I wasn't able to resolve my issues using the other answers, but had success once I installed webdriver-manager.

Comment: On Mac it works for me but on Linux it doesn't, I get: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Comment: @D.L this doesn't work with Chrome Beta though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to locate the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) executable.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.39*
- As per this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551748/7429447) *chromedriver=2.39* :

> Supports Chrome v66-68

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=99.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v99.0.4844.51*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 99

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=2.39* and the *chrome=99.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.1.3***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99.0* (as per [chromedriver=99.0.4844.51 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).