# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 running Selenium Chrome Driver inside Python project

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am running the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

I have installed firefox under **/usr/bin/firefox** and geckodriver (same version) under **/usr/bin/geckodriver**

However, I am getting the following stacktrace error when the Python code is run:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/harshitsidhwa/WhatsApp-bot-selenium/blob/master/whatsapp.py

Comment: How are you getting _`['"917570090256"', '"Hello world"', '"sidhwa JIIT"', '"temp"']`_

Comment: it's a part of the script I am running, however the stack trace error occurs as the reason of some problem with selenium driver

Comment: try this for selenium webdrive:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603374/my-ide-gives-me-a-chrome-driver-error-when-trying-to-run-webbot/71626868#71626868

Comment: Check `/var/log/messages` or other system logger for more details. One of reasons might be wrong permissions. If so, then fix it with `sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/geckodriver` and `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/geckodriver` (applies to CentOS, RockyLinux or AlmaLinux, use similar for other distributions). Eventually find out where is firefox installed with `which geckodriver`.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session.

Possibly there are some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 4.1.3](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.30.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current *Firefox v98.0.2* levels.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message when I running Selenium 4 + Firefox on Centos 8

I check the log file `geckodriver.log`

It is showing

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
```

so I'm using a non-root user to run the same Python script, It is working now.