# Does Selenium 3 work with chrome browser version 83?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have been using Selenium 3 (selenium-java 3.141.59)with Chrome Driver version 77.
Lately we are trying use Chrome Driver version 83 or even Chrome Driver 107 with Selenium 3.
Does going to Chrome version 83 or 104 require an upgrade to Selenium 4?

Answer (score 0):

Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) and/or [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) broadly [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***major*** version must be in sync.

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Server terminated early with status 1 error with Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message "Only local connections are allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551748/7429447)
- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50697221/7429447)

---

However, using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and onwards [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) would automatically download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) and you can simply:

- *Python* sample code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- *Java* sample code block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```