# java - Selenium WebDriver failed to create chrome process

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, createprocess

So I have been trying to make a program that can interact with a webpage to input data. I ideally wanted to use Chrome so I tried to set up Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Chrome {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Set chromedriver path
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Comp Sci work/chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     // Open Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    // Maximize browser
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
}
```

I seem to have set up the external JARs correctly as I can import them with no problem. The problem is for some reason the Chrome process cannot be created. I thought this might've been because there was already a Chrome process open but no. I still got the same error when I killed the process.

I then tried to set reset the path to Chrome, as the default one might've been different to mine, but still no luck.

```
public class Chrome {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Set chromedriver path
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Comp Sci work/chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

     // Open Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    // Maximize browser
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
}
```

The error message is:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) 
on port 43997
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown 
error: Failed to create a Chrome process.
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 
(49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 199 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08- 
02T20:05:20.749Z'
```

As the chromedriver seems to start fine the problem is simply in creating the chrome process but I can't seem to find out why. Any help would be appreciated(Also tips about my post formatting, as this is my first post). Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify chrome browser version?

Comment: Yes of course, my chrome is up to date as of the time i'm writing this. 
Version 68.0.3440.106 (64-bit).

Comment: I have the same problem!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846079/only-local-connections-are-allowed-chrome-selenium-webdriver/42808127

Comment: Thank you for the link but it seems that thread addresses a different issue. My problem is that my WebDriver can't create a Chrome process. I've looked at any logs left behind but i can't seem to make any sense of them. I don't think the problem is in the server.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: No, unfortunately not, I'm now trying to make the program with Python and I seem to have gotten a bit further. @JohannesMols

Comment: I have this problem [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191422/webdriverexception-unknown-errors-chrome-failed-to-start-and-failed-to-crea).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I meet this problem today,and  solved it finally.it's because the chrome run as Administrator.so java can't start it.

Google Chrome Properties->Compatibility->not run as administrator

Comment: This absolutely fixed my issue on win10

Answer (score 4):

(for Mac) Change binary path from

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
```

..to:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```