# WebDriverException: unknown errors ("chrome failed to start" and "Failed to create a Chrome process")

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

After installing Katalon Studio **v.5.8.2** to a co-workers laptop, when trying to run the test, test fails with this exception

> Test FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: '' (Root cause: **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start**
>     (Driver info: **chromedriver=2.35.528161** (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 104 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   Driver info: driver.version: CChromeDriver)

After updating chromedriver to **2.43** I get a slightly different message

> Test FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: '' (Root cause: **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.**
>     (Driver info: **chromedriver=2.43.600210** (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 156 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   System info: host: '****', ip: '****', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_102
>   Driver info: driver.version: CChromeDriver)

```
 at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain.stepFailed(KeywordMain.groovy:36)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:65)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:27)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:53)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:60)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser$0.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
 at metode.medicus.ulogirajSeURL(medicus.groovy:80)
 at metode.medicus$ulogirajSeURL.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at Script1532094337023.run(Script1532094337023.groovy:13)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:183)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:108)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:294)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:264)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:256)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:200)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:99)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:90)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
 at TempTestCase1541595007628.run(TempTestCase1541595007628.groovy:22)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:507)
 at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:653)
 at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:384)
 at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)
 at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)
 at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
)
```

Both messages happen with Chrome **70**, and the same thing happens when I revert to Katalon Studio **v.5.8.0**. [**EDIT:** happens on v 5.8.6, too.]

Since this is not my machine, I am unable to change the Chrome version.

**EDIT:** there is this connected issue with Java and Selenium, but no solution: [java - Selenium WebDriver failed to create chrome process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851142/java-selenium-webdriver-failed-to-create-chrome-process).

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/53191422/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53191422/edit) and update with the error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking multiple questions. The error messages are connected, the second one is what I get after trying to solve the first. Could you please help me to understand more?

Comment: The the error stack trace from only single version of _ChromeDriver_, i.e. either _v2.35_ or _v2.43_ will make the analysis short and simple. Btw, why not to upgrade Selenium to _v3.141.5_? Please consider removing the `<blockquotes>` from the error logs else the log messages gets wrapped up and debugging the logs becomes difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I added error stack trace for v2.43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with user account rights.

It was solved by running Katalon as administrator.