# i've just changed pc and now i can't use selenium in python 3.10 scripts, in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium

the only one change was that i have a new pc. since this, each simple python 3.10 script using selenium module, is givin me this error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.

following my 'whole' code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('C:/chromedriver.exe'))
```

Comment: Did you try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489803/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-failed-to)?

Comment: Checkout the `chromedriver` path, make sure your `chromedriver` located on the same location provided

Comment: sure, it is on c:/chromedriver.exe

Comment: should probably be a "\"... and don't run it from root.... put it in your user folder.  Pretty sure Windows 10 has special permissions for root.  Also check to be sure Chrome is installed and working and that the major version matches the chromedriver major version.

Comment: chrome and chromedriver are same versions, and i copied chromedriver in many folders but nothing...same error