# Not able to execute script in chrome 91 using Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Recently my system got upgraded to Chrome 91, I also have updated the Chrome driver for 91 which got released on 4/12/21.
Using WebDriver version selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Now while executing the script, it's not opening the browser and showing WebDriverException with error message as 'Failed to create Chrome process'.
Attached screen shot with complete error.
[image: ErrorLogs]

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851142/java-selenium-webdriver-failed-to-create-chrome-process

Comment: I already have checked this and in my chrome properties window in 'Compatibility' tab all checkboxes are unchecked. Also the chek box for "Run this program as an admministrator" is unchecked and in disabled status, which appears under 'Previlege Level' section.

Comment: Paste the error code to the question.

Comment: I have attached the error codes with the question

Answer (score 0):

I've uninstalled the browser and removed the `Google` folder from `Program Files (x86)` and then downloaded and installed chrome again. After that it started working properly.