# How to make webapp run on Travis CI?

Tags: java, selenium, spring-mvc, travis-ci

Well, I've got a tomcat based web application written with Java and Spring-MVC framework (and Maven) where I use Selenium in order to test some pages.

Before tests I have the following setup:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    webDriver.get("localhost:8080/app/login");
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

If I run the app on my local machine and then run tests, everything works perfectly.

The issue is that If I want the app to be tested with Selenium, it must be running(otherwise, how would I connect to localhost?). But how is it possible to make webapp run on Travis CI before the app starts to check tests?

Maybe there are some third-party resources I should use? Or it can be done with Travis CI alone?

I know that on Heroku there's webapp-runner to start your webapp but is there any tool for Travis?

**Updated.**

So far the only idea I've got is to deploy and start the app on Heroku and then use that already running app in Selenium tests. So it would be like that in tests:

```
webDriver.get("someHerokuUrl");
```

And every push to Github will be like that: the app is autodeployed on Heroku and then the app is tested on Travis CI.

But I feel like it's a wrong way.

My .travis.yml config:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk8
sudo: required
dist: trusty
addons: # get google-chrome-stable
  apt:
    packages:
      - google-chrome-stable
before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3 
install: 
  - wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
  - unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
  - rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - sudo mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
  - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

on .travis.yml

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```

after you need use chrome **headless** mode or add XVFB plugin. Official doc [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-xvfb-to-run-tests-that-require-a-gui).

You can find a full sample [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi)

**JUnit test OK**

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.github.noraui.utils.Utilities.OperatingSystem;
import com.github.noraui.utils.Utilities.SystemArchitecture;

/**
 * Unit test for
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268198/how-to-make-webapp-run-on-travis-ci.
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AppTest {

    /**
     * Specific logger
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppTest.class);

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        final OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
        String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s",
                currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
                SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(),
                currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());
        if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
            logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
        }
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
    }

    @After
    public void quit() {
        this.webDriver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void read() {
        this.webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webDriver.get("http://localhost:" + port + "/app/login");
        logger.info(webDriver.getPageSource());
        assertThat(webDriver.getPageSource()).isEqualTo("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head></head><body>Hello stackoverflow.com questions 53268198</body></html>");
    }
}
```

**Trace on Travis-ci:**

[image]

You can find all this code on github [here](https://github.com/sgrillon14/stackoverflow.-53268198)

Comment: I have similar to your travis config(added to the post). But I still can't find out how to run my app on Travis so that tests can be passed(as I need my app running to be tested).

Comment: I've had a look at your full sample, but I can't see the solution to my problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can find a more simple sample here: https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi-POC/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/bot/FirstSimpleBotWithHeadless.java and .travis.yml file on root repository

Comment: It looks like either I misled you or I misunderstand you. Well, [there](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi-POC/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/bot/FirstSimpleBotWithHeadless.java#L45), driver directs to google.com. I'm able to do so as well. The issue is with localhost, I can't manage to test my own web application, because I can't get it running.

Comment: try add `http://` => `http://localhost:8080/app/login` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/login`

Comment: Doesn't work. Still shows that it can't locate the element, though it exists (looks like it can't direct to `http://localhost:8080/app/login`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work you've done, but I still can't get it working. In the example, you are using Spring-boot. As far as I know, Spring-boot uses embedded Tomcat server and thus you can easily run the application on Travis. But I do not use Spring-boot but Spring-MVC.
You can examine the project [here](https://github.com/THEWaterfall/test-app)

Comment: But how can I start the app on Travis CI side? On my local machine I have tomcat and with its help, the app with Spring-MVC can run.

Comment: So don't you know if there's a way to start my app on Travis CI side?

Comment: I started to look at this with the tomcat8-maven-plugin: https://github.com/sgrillon14/test-app