# Selenium ChromeDriver Cannot assign requested values

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The chromedriver for selenium has recently stopped being able to bind. I am able to launch the hub and the chromedriver, but once I start running the tests, there are errors shown below. Does anyone know if the recent ChromeDriver upgrade has changed something? (Am using the 3.141 version of selenium)

```
15:28:46.684 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (...-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port XXXX
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1572622126.697][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
15:28:49.324 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
15:28:49.329 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 2ff751ceeb9c34c517e24c43a983a3cb (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

And the driver options configuration:

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    AppContext.getEnv().setDriverPermissions(this);
    new DesiredCapabilities();
    ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
    ops.addArguments("--incognito");
    ops.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    ops.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
    ops.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    ops.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips");
    //ops.addArguments("--headless");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", AppContext.getEnv().getDriverPath(this));
    return new ChromeDriver(ops);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "\[SEVERE\]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)" while starting chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844788/how-to-fix-severe-bind-failed-cannot-assign-requested-address-99-while)

Comment: No, I tried that, but didn't work