# bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: selenium

When I use selenium for testing, I often receive such an error message.

```
[1594632374.976][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

I don't know if this will affect the test results. And I added `--whitelisted-ips`, it will still cause this problem

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844788/how-to-fix-severe-bind-failed-cannot-assign-requested-address-99-while?rq=1) discussion might help you.

Comment: I checked the document and now I think that the way I added `whitelisted-ips` was wrong. Because I added it directly to `chromeOptions.args`, but I just checked the `chromeOptions.args` documentation and there is no `whitelisted-ips`. Do you know how to use `whitelisted-ips` with `selenium-side-runner`?