# Creating a docker image to run Selenium tests in container

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Selenium tests in the docker container. However, when I try to run the test, I get the following message:

```
ui-test    | stderr: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
ui-test    | 
ui-test    | stdout: 
ui-test    | ===============================================
ui-test    | uiTestsSuite
ui-test    | Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 4
ui-test    | Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 7
ui-test    | ===============================================
ui-test    | 
ui-test    | 
ui-test    | child process exited with code 0
```

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
RUN yum -y install vim
RUN yum -y install wget

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.9.0/node-v14.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf node-v* -C /usr/local

# Install dependencies.
RUN yum update
RUN yum install -y unzip openjdk-8-jre-headless xorg-x11-server-Xvfb libXi-devel GConf2-devel google-chrome

# Install ChromeDriver.
RUN wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
RUN unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
RUN rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Selenium.
RUN wget -N http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -P ~/
RUN mv -f ~/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar
RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar
RUN chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar

EXPOSE 3000

ADD src/ src/
ADD rest/ rest/
ADD target/ui-tests.jar ui-tests.jar

RUN cd rest && npm install
RUN npm install express --save

ENTRYPOINT node rest/index.js
```

And docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ui-test:
    build: ./
    container_name: ui-test
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Does anyone know why my tests are skipped when I try to run them in docker?
When I run those tests without docker, they work fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "\[SEVERE\]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)" while starting chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844788/how-to-fix-severe-bind-failed-cannot-assign-requested-address-99-while)

Comment: @Stefano Yes, the ChromeDriver is starting now, but the tests are still skipped, and it says that there's a configuration error.

Comment: did you increase the verbosity of your chromedriver? is it giving more info? at the moment there's not much info in your output.