# Chromedriver executable path not found in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I have created a docker image with the Docker file below. It installs the latest versions of Google Chrome and the chrome driver. As well as the other pip packages.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

# Install Chrome WebDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /seltesting

COPY ./app ./app

CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]
```

The chromedriver.exe file is in the container as I have found it in the CLI. It is in this directory '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.

python code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

I am using a venv as I am also using flask to create a micro service that uses the chrome driver. Would that be causing an issue?

Any assist would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: Are you able to start that executable manually in the container?

Comment: Also can you share the exact text of the error you get?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyR. thank you so much for your help when I execute the file in the container I get this message - Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1630890753.041][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Comment: Try to apply this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844788/how-to-fix-severe-bind-failed-cannot-assign-requested-address-99-while

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thank you for the assistance. I have just tried that solution and even though I do not get that error anymore. The chrome driver can still not be found. Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully

I am trying to run the chromedriver within a Flask application, would you know if this may be causing me issues?

Comment: What do you mean? The message you are showing means you have successfully started your driver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the problem, you need to add the all the python files into the Dockerfile. Please find the Dockerfile to install the Chromedriver and Chrome onto the image and the default path for the chromedriver within the container.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD /app/main.py .
ADD /app/connectdriver.py .

# Install Chrome WebDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /seleniumtesting

COPY ./app ./app


CMD ["python","./app/main.py"]
```

python driver script

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

Comment: The chromewebdrive and google chrome worked for me, but a couple of updates. 1) On Mac M1 silicon I had to add a `--platform` flag in the FROM statement: `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.11.6-slim-bookworm` 2) `executable_path` is no longer supported in selenium 4.10.0+

Answer (score 2):

In Python-Selenium I wouldn't pass the chromedriver path, instead I will use auto installer, so that it won't fail in such cases.

### chromedriver-autoinstaller

Automatically download and install `chromedriver` that supports the currently installed version of `chrome`. This installer supports `Linux`, `MacOS` and `Windows operating systems.`

### Installation

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

### Usage

Just type import `chromedriver_autoinstaller` in the module you want to use chromedriver.

### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

### Conclusion :

If you see above, I have not pass any path instead it is just, `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` preceded by `chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()`, should help you past the issue.

[Official Reference link](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/)

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey, I have tried this but unfortunately it did not work :(. I tried both ways of the configuration but no luck :( Thank you for you help though :).

Comment: Ideally it should have been, what went wrong with this technique ?

Comment: it is still saying that the driver cannot be found. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

Comment: Cause I think you missed to run `pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller` beforehand. Cause in my solution, you do not need to have a physical copy of `chromdriver.exe`

Comment: sorry i did install the chromedriver-autoinstaller into the container and the requirements.txt page. As 'chromedriver-autoinstaller==0.2.2'

Comment: Not working with base image `python:3.10.7-bullseye`, Chrome binary are not found.

Comment: This one is quite a lot buggy. I encountered some path lookup without catch.