# Chrome failed to start: crashed while running test cases using Docker - the process started from chrome location /opt/chrome/chrome is not longer

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

The process started from chrome location /opt/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed) error message appeared while running UI test cases using selenium , python and chrome driver)

I am attempting to run the test cases using Selenium Python via Docker and am encountering several difficulties.

Here is tech stalk information,

Selenium: 4.12.0

Python version: 3.10

Chrome Driver:

```
117.0.5938.88
```

Chrome Binary:

```
117.0.5938.88
```

Docker File:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9.2023.04.17.20 as build
RUN yum install -y unzip && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip" "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.88/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip" && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chrome-linux64.zip" "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.88/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip" && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /opt/ && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /opt/

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9.2023.04.17.20
RUN yum install -q atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib \
    libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver \
    libXtst pango at-spi2-atk libXt xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
    xorg-x11-xauth dbus-glib dbus-glib-devel -y

COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux64 /opt/chrome
COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver-linux64 /opt/

COPY pyproject.toml ./
COPY src ./src

COPY ./modernca.cer ./artifactory_ng.crt
COPY ./requirementss.txt ./
COPY ./.netrc /root/.netrc
RUN chmod 600 /root/.netrc

RUN  CERT_PATH="./artifactory_ng.crt" NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=${CERT_PATH} REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=${CERT_PATH} NO_VERIFY_SSL=true pip install -q -r requirementss.txt
RUN pip install datadog-lambda ddtrace
RUN rm -rf artifactory_ng.crt
RUN rm -rf /root/.netrc

RUN yum update -y libcurl curl python-libs python libxml2 openssl-libs openssl nss-sysinit nss nss-tools libdb-utils libdb cpio ca-certificates
COPY --from=public.ecr.aws/datadog/lambda-extension:latest /opt/extensions/ /opt/extensions

#CMD [ "datadog_lambda.handler.handler" ]
CMD [ "src.lambdas.ui_automation.handler" ]
```

When I run the test case in local it is working fine without any issues,

But same test case is failing when running in the docker.

I open the docker locally and I see the folder opt/chrome/chrome..

my selenium driver

```
from seleniumwire.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/opt/chrome/chrome'
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')        
chrome_driver_service = Service(executable_path='/opt/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_service,
                                      options=options
                                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in `wire` mode + `headless` mode, which works on any environment.

`pip install seleniumbase` - and run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(wire=True, headless=True)
try:
    driver.get("https://wikipedia.org")
    for request in driver.requests:
        print(request.url)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

The output I got for that:

```
https://wikipedia.org/
https://www.wikipedia.org/
https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/js/index-6852360a56.js
https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png
https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/js/gt-ie9-ce3fe8e88d.js
https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/sprite-8bb90067.svg
https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikinews-logo_sister@2x.png
```

Comment: Hi, I have those options too (I didn't add all the full code) but it still throws me the error.

Comment: I added a `seleniumbase` solution. It's a framework that automatically configures settings based on the environment. (Using `wire` mode and `headless` mode.)

Comment: (Technically, I replaced my first answer with the new one, since you just edited the question by adding those options.)

Comment: I prefer not to use another library..do you have another solution?

Comment: You'll run into this without something like `pyvirtualdisplay` or `sbvirtualdisplay`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26070834/7058266

Comment: but locally it works for me, I want it work in docker env in aws.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the ChromeDriver with the `--whitelisted-ips` flag (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328161/1288109 ).