# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to do some training Java Selenium testing, and I'm having trouble running the web driver...
My code is very simple and yet, it won't work.
I'm working on macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3 .

My code is :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.junit.Assert;

/**
 * Created by wizzz-mac on 08/02/2017.
 */
public class FirstTest {

    @Test
    public void startWebDriver(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/wizzz-mac/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println(wd.getTitle());
        wd.close();
        wd.quit();
    }
}
```

And this is the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myFirstSeleniumProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myFirstSeleniumProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is the error I get :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/IdeaProjects/myFirstSeleniumProject/target/test-classes:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.53.1/selenium-java-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/2.53.1/selenium-edge-driver-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/htmlunit-driver/2.21/htmlunit-driver-2.21.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.21/htmlunit-2.21.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.2/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.17/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/neko-htmlunit/2.21/neko-htmlunit-2.21.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/cssparser/cssparser/0.9.18/cssparser-0.9.18.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-client-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.15.v20160210/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.15.v20160210/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-common-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-api-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.53.1/selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/2.53.1/selenium-ie-driver-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.53.1/selenium-safari-driver-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.5.7.Final/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.53.1/selenium-support-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-leg-rc/2.53.1/selenium-leg-rc-2.53.1.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.9.0/selenium-chrome-driver-2.9.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.9.0/selenium-remote-driver-2.9.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20080701/json-20080701.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.9.0/selenium-api-2.9.0.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/r09/guava-r09.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.2/httpcore-4.1.2.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/Users/wizzz-mac/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 FirstTest,startWebDriver
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 15818
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 60.36 seconds
Build info: version: '2.9.0', revision: '14289', time: '2011-10-20 23:22:17'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at FirstTest.startWebDriver(FirstTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I think that the problem is the part below:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 15818
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the chromedriver? If not, try updating it.

Comment: if you can see, iv'e set the property of the chrome driver to be the newest chromedriver which i downloaded from the internet. so it's not seems to be the problem

Comment: And does your browser open correctly? If not, this might be a duplicate issue of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect

Comment: having the same problem, did anyone get any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers did not resolve the problem - my solution is pretty simple: I just reinstalled Chrome (not **chromedriver**) and - it works.

Comment: Sure. Besides: consider cleaning up no-longer needed comments.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running this within docker,you might need to pass docker run command

```
--privileged
```

Comment: i'm not using docker, a simple selenium test that runs on Intellij on mac os, nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error is shown when there is a initialization problem with the driver with we interact. Change it to.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Users\\wizzz-mac\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: When referring to file paths in Java on Windows, you can use either doubled backslash or forward slash.  The java.io.File class takes either one.  However, this is for MacOSX, so, forward slashes are what's needed.  Besides, on Windows it would have had a drive letter.