# Setting up selenium, chromedriver, and wdio mixed with vagrant or docker

Tags: selenium, vagrant, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I started out trying to learn how to write automated tests for a small project but nothing was working right out of the box. After a couple hours of searching & experimenting I found the right configuration for my project & figured sharing it might help folks in the future.

Here's a small summary of the errors I encountered on this debugging journey:

- Using Jasmine & WDIO, `send_keys` was crashing

  - It was a Firefox/geckodriver bug, or something like that
- WDIO appeared to hang after switching from Firefox to Chrome

  - Chrome needed to be run in `--no-sandbox` mode, essentially

I figured my problem was probably stemming from having WDIO execute my tests on my local machine while Selenium was hammering on the browser in a Vagrant VM. So this will mainly be applicable for people using separate environments (vagrant->local, vagrant->vagrant, docker->local, etc) for WDIO & Selenium/Chromedriver. [Here is a gist of the configuration file I ended up with.](https://gist.github.com/anjunatl/4ce7043ede9236aa9e7713c6d4c8ffe1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with [fanatique/vagrant-selenium-vm](https://github.com/fanatique/vagrant-selenium-vm) and modified it to use Chrome instead of Firefox [because send_keys was broken with Firefox/geckodriver at the time of writing](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/647). After swapping out the packages, I'd start the tests with wdio but it would appear to hang. Turning on verbose logging showed it trying to start but failing with no explanation why.

```
[00:06:39]  COMMAND POST     "/wd/hub/session"
[00:06:39]  DATA        {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"chrome","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.6.2","name":"webdriverio"}}}
```

It took removing the `&` from the `nohup java ...` command in [fanatique/vagrant-selenium-vm](https://github.com/fanatique/vagrant-selenium-vm)'s `setup.sh` to see the logs from Selenium in real time, then I was able to see a `"only local connections are allowed"` message from `chromedriver`. That led me to [a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect) that said to add `--whitelisted-ips=""` as an arg to chromedriver - but I was still getting the *local connections* error message. Chrome itself ended up needing a `--no-sandbox` flag - that allowed WDIO to connect to the chromedriver in Selenium and my tests ran from there.