# Could not run Chrome driver on linux server using an executable jar file

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver, executable-jar

I am trying to run an executable jar file which will execute a test suite(using selenium/ cucumber) on linux environment by using the command java -jar -webdriver.chrome.driver=pathofchromedriver myjarfile.jar

I have the following error :

Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 29256
Only local connections are allowed.
[1534896949.211][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=99: Cannot assign requested address (99)

I tried to change the chrome driver version but it's not working. Does anybody knows how to fix it please?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect