# Unable to run Java Selenium tests in Jenkins locally using maven using ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am running  jenkins from tomcat 9 with jenkins . I have configured maven project with following commands in windows batch command.

```
c:cd C:\Users\Nikhil Udgirkar\workspace\Neon_workspace2\orangehrm
```

mvn clean test
echo Success

Also configured maven and jdk installations in jenkins

The browser is not launching at all. The execution is stopped at this line only

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 39673
Only local connections are allowed.
Mar 25, 2019 9:00:13 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

The test case execution was supposed to start but it is not starting with run paused after aforementioned line in console. Please help
Thanks

Comment: This is actually an info message, not an error. See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect). 

Also you're ChromeDriver is probably outdated. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html Current Version is **2.46**. Update and try again.

Comment: maybe you have issue similar to this one:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/selenium-java-1553593587-996severe-timed-out-receiving-message-from-rend/38456#38456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved after I created a slave. The tests were getting launched as usual and were visible on foreground with chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 39673
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver v2.36** was used to initiate a new **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following:

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- Possibly you are using the currently released *chrome=73.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.36* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v73*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: But when I launch test from testng/pom.xml they run. If there were genuinely issues with drivers the test would not run at all.

Comment: It is only when I trigger execution from Jenkins test do not run

Comment: Executing a script as _Java Program_, _using TestNG_, as a _TestNG suite_, through _Jenkins_, etc are pretty much different. Though the basic idea and output is identical but the flows are a bit different.

Comment: Okay will try this evening

Comment: Updated  the driver to both chromedriver 73 and 2.46 but not working