# Test with spring boot and selenium does not work with embedded server

Tags: java, spring, maven, selenium, spring-boot

Hello guys I'm using java 8 / Maven / Spring boot with Spring Security

ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 and Chrome with corresponding version.

I am trying to create a test with Selenium and I have a problem!

If I put the youtube, google or other site the browser opens in the test and runs OK, but when I try localhost: 8080 doesn't open my page!

I also get a warning!

Has anyone ever experienced this?

My dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Test Code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringbootTestApplicationTests {

WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void when_the_test_starts() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "**chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
}

@Test
public void test_login_page() {

    WebElement surname = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
    surname.sendKeys("gmail@gmail.com");

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    password.sendKeys("1");

    WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_login"));
    btn.click();

    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    assertEquals(url, "http://localhost:8080/dashboard");
}

@After
public void when_the_test_ends() {
    driver.close();
}
}
```

Warning

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140 
(2d9f97485c7b07dc18a74666574f19176731995c-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1155}) on 
port 38921
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Comment: you can get the answer with details here [stackoverflow chrome webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect)

Comment: I saw this post a few times and couldn't understand exactly what to do and what the real problem is.

Comment: connections to the HTTP server started by the language bindings (Java, Python, Ruby, .NET, etc.) are only allowed to come from other processes on the same host

Comment: Do you have any tip? some framework!

Comment: try your ip address instead of localhost

Comment: I already tried it without success

Comment: try firefox driver instead of chrome  driver

Comment: does not work! I will keep looking for a solution

Comment: change chrome driver dependency version and update us if it works

Comment: tried it without success